# how to clear facebook share cache (non-debugger as doesn't)

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Facebook debugger tool pulls in correctly, with no errors, and all update to date info via the page meta. However, actual share button still pulls in old  `<meta property="og:title"` I've tried the refetching via debugger tool; again all this shows fine, but doesn't change what actual URL is sharing.. I've also tried method with adding the `?v=1` at end of share URL. Again, once done it shows fine, but back to using original share on page, still pulls out dated meta title. It is indefinitely cache because the code has nothing related to old data that is pulling in. Any pointers?

Comment: I've seen this happen.  In some cases, it takes a little time for their servers to sync up.  So it might APPEAR that your page is cached.  But it will fix itself up in short time.  Try checking it from a totally different device on a different network (like your cell phone)

Comment: Well. I've already waited about 12 hours...

Comment: And you're positive that the property information in the meta tag is the EXACT page that the debugger is pulling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

I plugged this into facebook debugger;

```
http://www.website.com/
```

And apparently it needed to be; with full file name:

```
http://www.website.com/index.htm
```